# Stefan Problem With Time Boundary Conditions

Tags: boundary-value-problem

I have doubt on Stefan Problem with time boundary conditions, does this problem has an analytical solution or not? For example in the following article

*Tao, L. N.*, [**The Stefan problem with arbitrary initial and boundary conditions**](https://doi.org/10.1090/qam/508769), Q. Appl. Math. 36, 223-233 (1978). [ZBL0396.76075](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0396.76075).

They obtain some kind of analytical solution but I do not get how this is solution is different from a problem with non-time dependent boundary conditions, because actually they have an special solution with this condition